# How Can I Deserialize Json With F#?

Tags: f#, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize some very simple json into F# with Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.4:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "C:/Users/OCatenacci/fshacks/CreateWeeklySWEEventsEmail/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.4/lib/net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
#endif 

open System
open Newtonsoft.Json

type meta() = class
    member val count = 0 with get, set
    end

let testjson = """{
    "meta": {
        "count": 15
    }
}"""


let o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<meta>(testjson)
```

meta always gets a 0 in the count.  By the way, I was originally defining meta like this:

```
type meta = {
   count: int
}
```

And I changed to using the Automatic property because I thought that Newtonsoft.Json might not be able to construct the object correctly.

I would be surprised if my version of F#/Windows makes a difference in this case but just for sake of completeness: I'm trying this with the F# 3.0 Repl (11.0.60315.1) and I'm running on a Win7 x64 (SP1) box.

Comment: Have you considered using the F# JSON type provider? http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

Comment: @JonnyBoats that'd be fine if type providers were supported with mono.  I want this to be able to run with mono as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing the outer-most set of curly braces from your JSON. Right now, you have an object containing an instance of `meta`. That's probably throwing off JSON.NET. In other words, I got it to run fine by using:

```
let testjson = "{ 'count' : 15 }"
```

*[Updated base on comments]*

Alternately, you could keep the JSON as-is, and provide a more complex type tree in F#. For example:

```
type Foo =
  { meta : Meta }
and Meta =
  { count : int }
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion but the actual json will contain the outer name so I need to figure out how to deserialize that too.  I am quite puzzled as to the nature of the problem; as you say if the format of the json changes, it deserializes fine so it doesn't seem to be an F# problem.

Comment: All you need to do, then, is define another type which has `meta` as a member. Then deserialize to _that_ type. Something like `type Foo = { meta : Meta } and Meta = { count : int }`.

Comment: You know I wonder if this has something to do with the F# type inference mechanism for a record type.  Of course if that were the case you'd think the other method (the automatic members) would work.

Comment: It's just a mismatch between the type hierarchy as F# sees it versus what's encoded in the JSON. Afterall, every `{` ... `}` pair in JSON is another object (in the type-instance sense).

Answer (score 10):

With [FSharp.Json](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Json) library you can use just record types - no need to define classes anymore. Structure of records provided above is just enough:

```
type Foo =
  { meta : Meta }
and Meta =
  { count : int }

let testjson = """{"meta": {"count": 15}}"""

open FSharp.Json
let data = Json.deserialize<Foo> testjson
```

Disclosure: I'm author of FSharp.Json library.